# How do I inspect the "Debug View Hierarchy" while iOS device is plugged?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, debugging, view-hierarchy

I know that *"Debug View Hierarchy"* work on 32-bit Mac App Projects and it doesn't support every type of iOS Simulator. But I can use on some of iOS Simulator.

Right now, I'm using `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`. Obviously it doesn't active on iOS Simulator.

So my question is, is there any way to inspect on iOS device?
Could you please give me an advice?

Answer (score 0):

The button works just fine when i'm compiling on an iOS device. Just use it the same way you would with your simulator.